# OpenLayers with geowebcache - WMTS vs. WMS

Tags: gis, openlayers, openlayers-3, geoserver, wms

I am using OpenLayers 3 with GeoWebCache (GeoServer). Are there any performance differences between WMS and WMTS when using GeoWebCache?

(Now I'm using url *http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms* and I want to know if it will be faster to use WMTS instead)

Comment: Take a look at this:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53011/difference-between-a-wmts-and-a-wms

Comment: but in the first time there is no cache, so maybe it will be faster to use wmts?

Comment: I might be wrong but if you're using GeoWebCache the tiles have to be generated beforehand, and therefore they will be cached.

Comment: Thanks! i have also checked it and indeed the tiles was 256X256

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/206057/115